# What is faster for creatin a matrix, using np.hstack (or np.vstack) inside a for loop, or changing the columns of a previously created np.zeros array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a matrix inside a for loop (one column at a time).
Which is the faster way to do it? creating a `np.empty()` array and using `np.hstack()` to append the columns, or creating a `np.zeros()` array of the desired shape and changing the columns of the array.

TIA

Comment: What's with this `np.empty()`?  What shape?  Have you experiment?  Done some timings?

Comment: Repeated `hstack` (or other versions of `concatenate`) make a **new** array each time, with a full copy.  Do you think that will be fast?   In many SO questions, the recommendation has been to either assign values to a preallocated array, or to use list append to collect columns, and do one 'stack' at the end.  But do some of your testing!

Comment: Kindly show the code for your *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* with representative sizes and somebody may be able to assist you more decisively... else we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.zeros()` be faster when the size is big enough that the array operations are significant.

The reason for that is that numpy arrays are stored continuously in one big block of memory. Allocating memory for the array takes time. When using `hstack` you continuously need to grow the memory for the array, which means re-allocating the memory and copying all the data to the new place, making this essentially an `O(n^2)` operation. Pre-allocating with `np.zeros` saves you this time.